# PHP curl to display output for URL like 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'

Tags: php, http, curl

I am trying to get the response/status code including the header for multiple URL's. My first try I was successful in getting the status code i.e. 200 or 301 or 302. But I want the output to be like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` or `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` etc.

Below is my code in which I get just the response code i.e. `200` or `301.`

```
<?php
$line = "https://www.pnc.com";
        $ch = curl_init($line);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $line);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
        $out = curl_exec($ch);
        $ret = true;
        if ($out !== false) {
                $statuscode = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                echo "Response Code:" .$statuscode. "\r";
        }
        curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Actual Ouput

```
Response Code:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ETag: "846caf551746b12e876c0bad5a50830d:1475788950"
Last-Modified: Thu, 06 Oct 2016 21:22:30 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 17609
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Fri, 21 Sep 2018 15:35:01 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Fri, 21 Sep 2018 15:35:01 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Expected Output

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK.
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using    [strtok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)

Example:

```
$statuscode = strtok( $statuscode, "\n" );
```

-or-

Using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is pretty standard:

```
$statuscode = explode( "\n", $statuscode )[0];
```

There are definitely other methods as well

However probably the cleanest way might be to use cURL itself:

```
$response = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
```

Comment: I used this but I'm not getting the desired result. Also, I am trying to hardcode the values so I am using switch. But still no result.